# Disable SharePoint Site Managment log-in prompt

Tags: windows, sharepoint, server-administration

I've set up two sites using SharePoint. However, certian pages that require Administration privileges, when visited by end-users trigger a log in prompt.
Can I disable it completely, and make administration only possible on local enviroment?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TrrC.png)

Asked a developer friend of mine, who say it's normal behaviour.

Comment: Please check this document to see if it helps you?https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/04/sharepoint-keeps-asking-for-password.html